# Http вычитать буфер перед посылкой ответа?

Tags: c, http, post, tcp, xmlhttprequest

Имеем HTTP протокол, POST запрос, конкретнее передачи больших файлов. Ситуация заключает в том, что клиент не принимает ответ до момента пока не передаст все данные. Отосланный ответ им просто не читается (браузер XmlHttpRequest), сеанс заканчиваеться на connection refused.

Задача при каких то параметрах запроса, отклонить передачу и послать стандартный ответ, например 403. Есть ли какой элегантный способ решить эту задачу? На текущий момент приходиться вычитывать все байты recv () и только потом отсылать ответ. Но это весьма долго и не красиво, файлы размером более 5Мб. Вопрос интересуюся применительно к C, хотя подойдут любые полезные советы :)

Вопрос соответственно про сторону сервера, крутиться понимание что то типа использовать TCP_nodelay, отключить Лингер и shutdown с SHUT_RW - но эксперименты ничего толком не дали. Клиент не слышит ничего пока не пошлет все данные.

(Чего то там не хватает чтоб оставить комментарии..)

напишу тут:
именно отправить ответ, например 403 и не получается!
Вернее отправить получается, send(), потом shutdown(), потом close()
но, клиент не получает его, а пишет connect refused..
Клиент XmlHttpRequest, он шлёт все данные без остановки, после получения Http хеадера нет возможности прервать его передачу данных.

Если же вычитать все данные которые он там посылает, а после этого отправить 403, то все в порядке, он это видит.

Требуется что то что заставит его прекратить слать всякую чепуху и послушать что скажут после отосланного хеадера :)

Возможно причина в самом XmlHttpRequest'е, или я его не так использую..
Что маловероятно

Минимальный пример TCP сервера все равно займёт много места, там нет специфического кода, после accept() вызываеться recv(), далее анализ полученных заголовков и сразу отсылаеться 403 ответ методом send() далее shutdown() и close() - это собственно все, тут подводных камней вроде быть не может.

Со стороны js клиент идентичен примеру например из https://learn.javascript.ru/xhr-onprogress

ещё раз уточню, клиент принимает ответ если вычитать все данные которые он посылает.

Comment: если я правильно понял, то по идее нужно просто отправить клиенту ответ и закрыть соединение... небольшой отрывок кода сервера прояснил бы ситуацию...

Comment: Да, ответить http 413 и можно закрывать соединение чтобы клиент не пытался продолжать отправлять данные. Именно такое поведение в стандарте и описано: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-10.4.14 (с обновлением заголовка в https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.11 )

Comment: [справка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: >>клиент не получает его, а пишет connect refused<< — ИМХО одно из двух: или клиент некорректно обрабатывает ответ, или что-то сделано не так... в любом случае необходим [mcve]

Comment: На стороне сервера следует сразу закладываться, что клиент тупой и ничего не соблюдает - если он продолжает что-то слать не обращая внимания на ответ - то это проблема клиента (а то может он это и специально делает, типа DoS).

Comment: Да, соглашусь, на сервере  учитывать возможное нестандартное поведение клиента. Но все же, мысль крутиться вокруг: послать shutdown() с закрытием передачи на том конце, при этом у клиента должен в трубе образоваться 0, и по логике он должен скинуть передачу. Потом включить в сокете TCP_NODELAY и возможно отключить Лингер на сокете, при этом скинуться буферы на локальном конце и передать ответ с последующим shutdown() и close(). В теории должно сработать, на практике пока неудаеться.

Comment: может это "взлом". Ко мне на сервер регулярно сыпятся "непонятные"  http запросы, на примере которых можно изучать "инжекцию" и другие современные методы взлома.

Comment: Отправка файла частями на клиент есть. Возможно вам нужно закачка файла частями....

Comment: @nick_n_a, don't comment this.. 8)